# How can I loop through OU in AD to add users to various security groups?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm somewhat new to writing PS scripts, I usually only need simple one or two liners, but for this I'm trying to loop through a specific OU in Active Directory to find each users department, add "grp" before it and add them to the security group by that name.  For example, a department might be something like 10005 so I'd like to add them to security group named "grp10005".  Here's what I have but it isn't working.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

 $users = $i = $null  
 $strCC
 $strGRP = 'grp' & strCC

 $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=OurUsers,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" -filter * {department -eq $strCC}  
 ForEach($user in $users)  
    {    
      Add-ADGroupMember 'strGRP' -Members $_.DistinguishedName
        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
      $i++  
    }
```

Comment: You have a number of syntax errors. `&` is the call operator not a way to concatenate strings. For which `strCC` in that statement is missing it's `$` as such PowerShell is looking for a keyword by that name. Then your filter specifies "All" with the `*` and then there is a scriptblock which throws an error as PowerShell is trying to put that scriptblock into another parameter based on its position. Also, the filter is using $strCC but nothing has yet been assigned to it so it is `$null`.

Comment: Additionally, you are using the pipeline variable `$_` in your foreach yet you are using `ForEach($user in $users)`. Which the whole point of using that form of foreach is to use `$user` instead of an ambiguous underscore.

Comment: The counter variable `$i` is also unnecessary since all you are doing is incrementing the counter and then never reading it for anything.

Comment: @NewGuy Even worse, `$null++` is still just `$null`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That's not what happens.  If `$i` doesn't exist, then `$i++` turns it into an int.  `Remove-Variable i -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; $i -eq $null; $i++; $i -eq $null; $i;` returns `True`, `False`, `1`.

Comment: @BaconBits Yes, but `$i` does exist. `$users = $i = $null`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Fair enough, but `$i = $null; $i -eq $null; $i++; $i -eq $null; $i;` *still* returns `True`, `False`, `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed the syntax errors and modified the approach a bit.

```powershell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$users = $null  
$strDept = "Finance"
$strGRP = ('grp' + $strDept)

$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=OurUsers,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" -Filter { Department -eq $strDept }  
ForEach($user in $users)  
{    
    Add-ADGroupMember 'strGRP' -Members $user.DistinguishedName
        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on the comments below it sounds like you are not wanting to use a filter at all but you want to check every user in the OU, find out what their current department is, then add them to a group by that name but with "grp" prefixed on to it.

Here is a possible solution:

```powershell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$users = $null  

$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=OurUsers,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" -Filter * -Properties Department
ForEach($user in $users)  
{    
    Add-ADGroupMember ("grp" + $user.Department) -Members $user.DistinguishedName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed but I just removed -Properties, does the {} on filter exclude those items? or only include them?

Comment: @RiCHiE The Active Directory cmdlet Filter parameters are used to specify a set of criteria that the AD objects must match in order to be returned by the command. For details on the syntax of this filter see the following: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28485.filters-with-powershell-active-directory-module-cmdlets.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

 $users = $null 
 $i = 0 
 $strCC = "CC"
 $strGRP = ("GroupName" + $strCC)

 $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=OurUsers,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" -filter {department -eq $strCC}  
 ForEach($user in $users)  
    {    
      Add-ADGroupMember $strGRP -Members $user.DistinguishedName `
        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
      $i++  
    }
```

Note the difference between the two types of loop:

```
$array | foreach-object {
Write-Host $_
}
```

and:

```
foreach ($item in $array) {
Write-Host $item
}
```

Comment: This code will throw errors as your filter statement is both specifying '*' and then the scriptblock part is being assigned to a different parameter for which PowerShell will be unable to find a match for and thus throw the error. My guess is the OP needs to remove the `*` completely since they are trying to search on the department.

Comment: You are completely right, I've just editted the above.